# Accessing USB printer without drivers

Tags: networking, raspberrypi

Wondering if there is a way to send and receive information form specifically [this](https://www.primera.com/lx900#software-target) printer over USB. There are no supported drivers for this.

My goal is to build a print server with a raspberry pi to connect the printer to the network to enable network printing.

Comment: Have you plugged it in yet to see if it a built in generic driver will work?

Comment: @Tim Unfortunately I don't have easy access to the machine as it is around 3 hours away from me. Just planning at the moment. If the generic driver did work would it also be able to send ink status?

Comment: It will depend on which driver is compatible. Be aware, the PI is arm so that could through another slew of issues into the works as well.